# ¿Cómo mapeo una columna para que al hacer SELECT aparezca un valor u otro según una condición?

Tags: mysql

me preguntaba como puedo hacer un export de varios datos de una tabla con otro nombre mediante script.

```
SELECT DISTINCT answer,sm_src,sm_dst,event from rt_calls,rt_queue_log WHERE (event='completeagent' OR event='completecaller' OR event='abandon' OR event='exitwithtimeout') AND callid=linkedid AND answer BETWEEN '2021-05-24 00:00:00' AND '2021-05-25 00:00:00';
```

De esta manera me saca una tabla tal que asi:

```
+---------------------+-----------+--------+----------------+
| answer              | sm_src    | sm_dst | event          |
+---------------------+-----------+--------+----------------+
| 2021-05-24 09:31:17 |           |        | COMPLETEAGENT  |
| 2021-05-24 09:32:36 | 768687568 | 994    | COMPLETEAGENT  |
| 2021-05-24 09:33:17 | 863736567 | 994    | COMPLETEAGENT  |
| 2021-05-24 09:37:22 | 123456789 | 997    | ABANDON        |
| 2021-05-24 09:42:00 | 456597689 | 997    | ABANDON        |
```

todo esto lo he transcrito a un script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fecha=$(date -d "last Monday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
host="localhost"
usuario="root"
pass="1234"
database="baseba"
args_sql="-h $host -u $usuario -p$pass -D $database -s -e"
mysql $args_sql "SELECT DISTINCT answer,sm_src,sm_dst,event from rt_calls,rt_queue_log WHERE (event='completeagent' OR event='completecaller' OR event='abandon' OR event='exitwithtimeout') AND callid=linkedid AND sm_type = 'inbound' AND answer >'$fecha' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ejemplo.csv';"
```

con esto así quiero que al hacer el export en el apartado sm_dst en vez de 994 salga naranja y en 997 salga verde es decir que sin modificar la base de datos me saque el nuevo nombre.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir que "salga naranja"? ¿A qué te refieres con el "nuevo nombre"?

Comment: que me sustituya el numero en este caso 944 por naranja al exportarlo en ejemplo.csv

Comment: puedes usar cosas del tipo `select ... case when sm_dst = 944 then 'naranja'` y similares. Pero vaya, es un tema de SQL, nada que tenga que ver con Linux.

Comment: El problema es que no se mucho de mysql aprendí hace apenas 3 días lo que era y estoy con esta incógnita.